# My app only connects to the firestore backend in mobile data and not wifi

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As the title says, I have an app which doesn't connect to the firestore backend if the device is using WiFi connection, but works perfectly fine when using mobile data.

This only applies when I'm using a physical device. It works fine when using an emulator and connected to a WiFi network.

Here's the error I get in my Log when using WiFi connection on a physical device:

> Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment.

Here's my Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abdul.ams">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.barcodescannerActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.attendActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.attendanceActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.admincreatemessageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.createmessageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.adminActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.addstudentActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.splashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.addcourseActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.homeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.registerActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Activities.resetActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.abdul.ams"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this anyhow? I am having the same issue. Occasionally it fails to fetch latest data, and works if I disable/enable wifi.

Comment: It turned out that my router's firewall was blocking the requests going to Firebase. Use another wifi connection to make sure that you're not having the same issue.